# How to reduce blank space meant for hidden fields in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

[image]

I have a jsp page which has lot of hidden fields in it which get displayed based on conditions. Below is the code for my jsp page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>E-Form </title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" src="/Eform/JS/common.js"></SCRIPT> 


<link href='/Eform/CSS/common.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</head>
<body>
<!--form action="/Eform/SendMail" method="post" id='Eform' name='Eform'-->
<form action="/Eform/SendMail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='Eform' name='Eform'>
    <table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" class="text1">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle">
                <img border="0" src="/Eform/Images/Header.GIF" />
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" class="headingText1">E-Form </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="50"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="middle">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" class="commonText1">

                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Account(Existing Customers) or Projected Monthly Balance(New Customers)* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"> 
                            <select tabindex="0" name="accOrBalType" id="accOrBalType" onchange="doClear();" class="text1">
                                <option selected value="">-- Select One & Enter a value in to text box below --</option>
                                <option value="1">Account(Existing Customers)</option>
                                <option  value="2">Projected Monthly Balance(New Customers)</option>    
                            </select>       
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id = "accountNumber" style = "visibility:hidden">
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Account Number* :</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"> <input type="text" class="text1" maxlength="20" name="accountNumber" size="20" onblur="selectFirst();" /></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr id = "monthlyBalance" style = "visibility:hidden">
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Projected Monthly Balance* :</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"> <input type="text" class="text1" maxlength="20" name="monthlyBalance"  size="20" onblur="selectFirst();" /></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr id = "accEnrol" style = "visibility:hidden">
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Is the account already enrolled in a checking package or program?* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"> <input type="radio" class="text1" name="accEnrol" id="accEnrolY" value="Yes" onclick="packageName();"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" id="accEnrolN" value="No" onclick="packageName();"> No</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr id = "packages" style = "visibility:hidden">
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Package Name* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="100" class="text1" name="packages" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Enrolled in Business Online* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"> <input type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" value="Yes"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" value="No"> No</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Company Name* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="100" class="text1" name="cmpName" id="cmpName" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Business Industry/Description Of Business Activity* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%" class="text1">
                            <textarea class="text1" rows="4" cols="61" name="bussAct" id="bussAct"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's First Name* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="15" class="text1" name="fName" id="fName" size="20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's Last Name* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="15" class="text1" name="lName" id="lName" size="20"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's Telephone* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%">
                            <input type="text" value=" +1-" size="1" readonly/>&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="contTellNo" id="contTellNo" class="text1" size="11" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's E-mail Address* :&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="20" valign="middle" align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="50" class="text1" name="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" size="30" /></td>
                            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like this

[image]

If you notice there is a huge gap between the first field and the second. The space is automatically left for all the hidden fields. It kinda looks awkward. I want to rectify this.

Comment: use style="display:none" instead of style="visibility:hidden" because the one you are using still allocate space for the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the style `visibility:hidden` hides an element but the element continues to take up its space on the screen.

Using the style `display:none` would hide the element and stop taking up space on the screen.

So simply replace all the`visibility:hidden` to `display:none`